# Create bsoncxx::builder::basic::document from a string?

Tags: mongo-cxx-driver

Is there a way to create a bsoncxx::builder::basic::document from a std::string?

I know how to build a document using mongocxx functions such as make_document, kvp, make_array, as well as through the streaming functions.

But what I want to know is if we can create a std::string representation of a document and make that into a bsoncxx::builder::basic::document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that this `std::string` contains JSON, then yes. You can invoke `bsoncxx::from_json`.

If, somehow, the `std::string` buffer contains BSON data rather than JSON, you could copy the data inside the string into a new buffer and use one of the first two `bsoncxx::document::value::value` constructors, which take ownership of a buffer.

You could also construct a temporary `bsoncxx::document::view` over the buffer in the `std::string` by passing the underlying `.data()` and `.length()` of the string to the two argument `bsoncxx::view::view` constructor, and then pass that view along to the appropriate `bsoncxx::value` constructor, which will copy the data in the view.

Comment: You are correct, I created some json files using a json library and from_json did did work!  But now that I'm getting more and more familiar using the mongocxx functions, I'll just stick with mongo's functions.  Thank you!